# Custom Mercurial on Windows

Tags: windows, mercurial, installation

There are some options for me for Mercurial on Windows (I know there is the .msi), most likely:

- Cygwin
- Bare Python

I'd like to keep a custom mercurial install with some extensions (most likely for GIT/SVN Integration) for three machines (Win32 / x64). So, its likely I'd need to keep the python runtime installed as well.

How would you suggest me managing that?

Thank you

UPDATE: TortoiseHG is an option, but I am concerned about: I only use CLI and MercurialEclipse, with no need to place a burden on my Windows Shell (and I am somewhat hardcore about that). Remember even with TortoiseHG I'd like to add custom extensions for stuff like GIT.

Comment: aldrinleal: are you aware that TortoiseHg comes with at least the necessary Subversion bindings for use with `hg convert` and hgsubversion?

Comment: @Martin Geisler, I will give a try anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to shameless steal Master Geisler's obvious answer:

> [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/)

It gives you everything. Even kdiff3.

I actually use it exclusively from cygwin. Makes you forget about Windows for a while.